# How to choose target and other features in OpenWRT buildroot?

Tags: openwrt

I have successfully cloned the OpenWRT buildroot from the subversion repository and I've been using it to build images that I run on Qemu. I can run the images in Qemu just fine.

Now I have tried to build an image for a router -- a Linksys WRT54GL -- but I couldn't find in the documentation how I should choose the target.

I *guess* that these are the correct options:

- I have chosen Broadcom BCM947xx/953xx
- In "Target images", I have chosen jffs2 and squashfs

Then, after compiling, I went to the directory `bin/brcm47xx`, and found a large number of images:

```
openwrt-brcm47xx-jffs2-128k.trx
openwrt-brcm47xx-jffs2-64k.trx
openwrt-brcm47xx-squashfs.trx
.
.
.
openwrt-wrt54g3g-em-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3g-em-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3g-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3g-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-jffs2.noheader.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54g3gv2-vf-squashfs.noheader.bin
openwrt-wrt54g-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54gs-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54g-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54gs-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt54gs_v4-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt54gs_v4-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrt610n_v1-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrt610n_v1-squashfs.bin
openwrt-wrtsl54gs-jffs2.bin
openwrt-wrtsl54gs-squashfs.bin
```

So my question is:

- How do I tell what to choose in `target system` and `target images`?
- From all the images generated, how do I know which one I should use (for example, the WRT54GL is not in the list above; how to tell if it's OK to use "`openwrt-wrt54g-jffs2.bin`"?
- What criteria can I use to decide if I'll use a jffs or a squashfs image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ### How do I tell what to choose in target system and target images?

`Target system` you can infer from the Target/Platform columns in the `Table of Hardware`:

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start

`Target images` depend on the intended use of the build but in most common cases (ie. image to put on a router) you want either `squashfs` or `jffs2`. See the *filesystems* link below.

---

> ### From all the images generated, how do I know which one I should use (for example, the WRT54GL is not in the list above; how to tell if it's OK to use "openwrt-wrt54g-jffs2.bin"?

If your router is not listed amongst the custom images you should probably use the generic image, eg: `openwrt-brcm47xx-squashfs.trx`

---

> ### What criteria can I use to decide if I'll use a jffs or a squashfs image?

From http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/filesystems:

**SquashFS**

> `+` taking up as little space as possible
>
> `+` allowing the implementation of an idiot proof FailSafe for recovery, since it is not possible to write to it
>
> `-` read only
>
> `-` waste space, since each time a file contained on it is modified, actually a copy of it is being copied to the second (JFFS2) partition

**JFFS**

> `+` is writable, has journaling and wear leveling
>
> `+` is cool
>
> `-` is compressed, so a program (opkg in particularly) cannot know in advance how much space a package will occupy

Don't be mislead about the read-only part tho

> All of the OpenWrt firmwares include a fully writable root filesystem that will remain intact across a power outage. The confusion is due to the fact that squashfs is a readonly filesystem; all OpenWrt firmwares also include a jffs2 partition -- the squashfs part of the filename refers only to the filesystem included in the firmware image; additional files or changes are stored on jffs2.
>
> - The squashfs partition will always contain all of the files exactly as they came with the firmware; you cannot change these without reflashing. (see #6)
> - The jffs2 partition contains only your changes to the filesystem; since squashfs still contains the original version, you can easily revert files back to their original state.
>
> It is possible to remove the squashfs partition by installing the jffs2 version of the firmware, but this isn't recommended -- it uses more space and lacks the above failsafe features.

Source: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=36636#p36636

If in doubt use `squashfs` as per http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware.download#filesystem